# Selenium Edge driver not initializing when called from ant process - java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to run some selenium tests in edge and I get this problem:

When I run them from a java environment (JDeveloper for instance) everything works fine. However, we have set up an ant process to call tests from command line. When I try to do that the WebDriver is not initialized and throws and unkown exception error.

I am pretty sure the error is not in the ant files, since if I run the same tests in chrome it works fine.

This is the part of code that's failing:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver","PathToFolder\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe"); 
DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.edge();
driver = new EdgeDriver(capability);
```

I am sure the problem is not in the path, since when I run it directly from the class it worksfine. Also, I have checked the build number and I have the correct MicrosoftWebDriver.exe, so that's not the issue either.

The error I get is the following:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unknown error
[java] Command duration or timeout: 1.20 seconds
[java] Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:55:52'
[java] System info: host: 'DIANA', ip: '10.0.75.1', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.7.0_79'
[java] Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver
```

**UPDATE**: 
I was able to recover full log and it is the flollowing:

```
java.lang.Error: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unknown error
Command duration or timeout: 1.01 seconds
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:55:52'
System info: host: 'FORMIGA', ip: '172.25.208.1', os.name: 'Windows 8', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.2', java.version: '1.7.0_25'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver
    at com.wiris.webtester.WebPage.<init>(WebPage.java:126)
    at com.wiris.webtester.Context.initBrowser(Context.java:377)
    at com.wiris.webtester.Context.browse(Context.java:284)
    at com.wiris.webtester.action.BrowseAction.onExecute(BrowseAction.java:25)
    at com.wiris.webtester.action.BaseAction.execute(BaseAction.java:15)
    at com.wiris.webtester.action.TestAction.test(TestAction.java:77)
    at com.wiris.util.test.TestFile.test(TestFile.java:48)
    at com.wiris.util.test.TestList.executeFiltered(TestList.java:187)
    at com.wiris.util.test.TestList.execute(TestList.java:138)
    at com.wiris.webtester.TesterMain.run(TesterMain.java:151)
    at com.wiris.webtester.TesterMain.main(TesterMain.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.run(ExecuteJava.java:221)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.execute(ExecuteJava.java:154)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.run(Java.java:834)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:228)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:137)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.execute(Java.java:110)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:402)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:441)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:441)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1376)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:857)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:236)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:287)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:113)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unknown error
Command duration or timeout: 1.01 seconds
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:55:52'
System info: host: 'FORMIGA', ip: '172.25.208.1', os.name: 'Windows 8', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.2', java.version: '1.7.0_25'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:647)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:247)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:129)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver.<init>(EdgeDriver.java:152)
    at org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver.<init>(EdgeDriver.java:120)
    at com.wiris.webtester.WebPage.<init>(WebPage.java:121)
    ... 75 more
```

Comment: Can you update the question with the complete error stack trace?

Comment: I was gonna update it and suddenly it seems to be fixed... If I get the error again I'll copy it!

Comment: The error happened again in a different machine. I edited with the full log!

Answer (score 0):

The error does gives us some hint as follows :

```
java.lang.Error: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unknown error
Command duration or timeout: 1.01 seconds
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:55:52'
System info: host: 'FORMIGA', ip: '172.25.208.1', os.name: 'Windows 8', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.2', java.version: '1.7.0_25'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver
```

Which essentially implies that `EdgeDriver` binary didn't get **detected** at all and being **uninitialized** throws an **Unknown error**.

Your main issue is the **version compatibility** among the binaries you are using as follows :

- You are using **`JDK Version 1.7.0_25`** [`as per the error stack trace within your question`]
- You are using **`Selenium Version 2.48.2`** (released **2015-10-09 19:55:52**) [`as per the error stack trace within your question`]
- You are using **`EdgeDriver`** (version **UNKNOWN** to us)
- You are using **`Edge Browser`** (version **UNKNOWN** to us)

### Analysis

It is clear :

- Your **`JDK Version`** is out of date.
- **`EdgeDriver`** binary not geting detected.

### Solution

- Update **`JDK`** to recent  [**`JDK 8u151`**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) level.
- Upgrade `Selenium` to  current levels [**`Version 3.8.1`**](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade `EdgeDriver` to  current [**`v5.16299`**](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/) levels.
- Upgrade `Edge Browser` to  supported level of [**`v16.16299`**](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/).
- `Clean` and `Re-Build` your project through your `IDE`.
- Clear the `Browser Cache`
- Run [**`CCleaner`**](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores.
- If your `Edge Browser` base version is too old, uninstall the `Web Browser` through [**`Revo Uninstaller`**](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) with `Moderate Scan` and install a recent **GA Released** version of the `Web Browser`.
- Execute your `Test` :

Comment: mmm if I do all the updates except selenium would it still work? We do not wish to update selenium since it would mean making some changes in the code for which we don't have time/people to get involved with.

Comment: @DianaVallverdu I feel that would be worth a try. In-case you fail you can always revert back.